# XPATH get root node of selected node

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

i use [Defiant.js](http://www.defiantjs.com/) where you can query json data with XPATH expressions. Now i want to select the root node of a search result.

**source code**

```
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "categories": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Category1"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Category2"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "categories": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Category1"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "categories": [{
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Category2"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Category3"
    }]
}];

var result = JSON.search(data, '//categories[contains(id, "2")]')
```

With that expression i get an array of two category objects

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Category2"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Category2"
}]
```

But i want to get the root objects of the hits

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "categories": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Category1"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Category2"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "categories": [{
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Category2"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Category3"
    }]
}]
```

Is it possible to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Basically, there is always only one root node in a valid XML, and selecting the root should be as simple as selecting the first node in the document :</s>

```
/*
```

I think the same concept applies to JSON when using defiant.js. There always only one JSON object acting as root.

Anyway, if you *really* want to start from the descendant node context, you can use `ancestor` axis to climb the tree arbitrary level up. Suppose we are currently in one of the descendant node, say `categories`, you can go up to the root node this way :

```
ancestor::*[not(parent::*)]
```

Example based on your JSON data would be something like these :

```
var xpath1 = '//categories[contains(id, "2")]/ancestor::*[not(parent::*)]';
var result1 = JSON.search(data, xpath1)

var xpath2 = '/*[not(parent::*) and .//categories[contains(id, "2")]]';
var result2 = JSON.search(data, xpath2)
```

**UPDATE :**

Seems that what you mean by "root" in this context is elements referenced by this xpath : `/*/*`.

If that is correct, you may want something like this (you can also replace `descendant::` with abbreviated version `.//`) :

```
/*/*[descendant::subcategories[contains(id, '4')]]
```

More generally :

```
/*/*[descendant::{some filter here}]
```

or maybe using `descendant-or-self` instead of `descendant` if your filter needs to include checking properties of the "root" JSON object too:

```
/*/*[descendant-or-self::{some filter here}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there

```
//*[categories[contains(id, "2")]]
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for your help. First i thought it is the solution, but it doesn't work for objects in 3rd level. Let's say 'categories' have 'subcategories' which i want to query. Can i get up to level 1 from there?

Comment: I have to say, that i don't know the level of the property i search for!

Comment: @DominikBarann can you post your JSON where the condition fails?

Comment: based on what you said, you would need another xpath statement. // should be recursive. I would guess it is something like: //*[categories[contains(id, "2")] or subcategories[contains(id, "2")]]

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear, but in my opinion

> select object with subcategory.id=3 OR subcategory.id=4 AND name=Test2

translates to

```
//*[name = 'Test2' and category/subcategories/id = '3' or category/subcategories/id = '4']
```

> [image]